# Laravel Socialite Twitter

Tags: laravel, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth, laravel-socialite

**Laravel Socialite Twitter (Oauth1)**

I am having trouble with twitter login via laravel socialite.

```
Socialite::driver('twitter')->user();
```

the code above throws an error with message:

> Argument 1 passed to League\OAuth1\Client\Server\Server::getTokenCredentials() must be an instance of League\OAuth1\Client\Credentials\TemporaryCredentials, null given

I checked Laravel Socialite documentation and it says that to get the user details of a twitter account, I should use

> Socialite::driver('twitter')->userFromTokenAndSecret($token, $tokenSecret);

instead of

> Socialite::driver('twitter')->user();

But it isn't explained how to get the *$token* and *$tokenSecret* parameter. I hard coded the *$token* and *$tokenSecret* using the keys in the twitter application but everytime I log in other account it still uses that account which I understand since the code is hard coded. Is there anyway to get the user's *$token* and *$tokenSecret* when they log in? Thank you

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You must obtain the `$token` and `$token_secret` from the request.

```
  $provider = "twitter"  
  $token = trim($request->input("provider_token"));
  $token_secret = trim($request->input("provider_token_secret"));
```

Then you can use them for OAuth1.0

```
Socialite::driver($provider)->userFromTokenAndSecret($token, $token_secret);
```

You cant use `Socialite::driver($provider)->user($token);` here because OAuth1.0 is used.

Comment: The callback request doesn't contain this information.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when using APIs.

E.g : get the oauth-url by using an API, then use it with (Javascript `window.open`).

You should keep the **token(identifier)/token_secret** during generation the oauth-url (Socialite puts them with a session).

```
$redirect = Socialite::driver('twitter')->redirect();
/** @var League\OAuth1\Client\Credentials\TemporaryCredentials $tmpCredentials */
$tmpCredentials = unserialize(Session::get('oauth_temp')); // serialized object
```

Or when setting `stateless` by passing a `false` value.

```
$redirect = Socialite::driver('twitter')->stateless(false)->redirect();
/** @var League\OAuth1\Client\Credentials\TemporaryCredentials $tmpCredentials */
$tmpCredentials = Session::get('oauth.temp');
```

Consider that the Socialite in the callback are going to try using the **oauth_temp/oauth.temp** session. But you lost the session.

---

As a solution, try using a new route, which can redirect directly to oauth-url.

Your oaut-url API (will be called by Javascript):

```
$redirect = Socialite::driver('twitter')->redirect();
/** @var League\OAuth1\Client\Credentials\TemporaryCredentials $tmpCredentials */
$tmpCredentials = unserialize(Session::get('oauth_temp')); // serialized object
return route('your-new-route', [
   'token' => $tmpCredentials->getIdentifier(),
   'secret' => $tmpCredentials->getSecret(),
   'url' => $redirect()->getTargetUrl(),
]);
```

Your new route :

```
$tmpCredentials = new \League\OAuth1\Client\Credentials\TemporaryCredentials;
$tmpCredentials->setIdentifier(request()->get('token'));
$tmpCredentials->setSecret(request()->get('secret'));
Session::put('oauth_temp', serialize($tmpCredentials));
return redirect(request()->get('url'));
```

And your callback :

```
/** @var \SocialiteProviders\Twitter\Provider $socialiteProvider */
$socialiteProvider = Socialite::driver('twitter');
$user = @$socialiteProvider->user();
```

With twitter provider, An error will be thrown during converting the Twitter result to the Socialite user object :

> ErrorException : Indirect modification of overloaded property SocialiteProviders\Manager\OAuth1\User::$urls has no effect

To avoid this issue, use the at sign (@) symbol.